How can I handle large keyword fields in OpenSearch?
I have an app where I index data in OpenSearch. The data model is largely defined by the end users and not by myself. So, when a user says that they have a "string" field, I index it both as a text and keyword field in OpenSearch because I don't know whether it's a short, enum-style string or long-form text. So my field mappings look like:
"example_field": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}

The problem arises when a user then supplies long-form text, and I get errors like:

Document contains at least one immense term in field="example_field.keyword" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.

I've tried setting ignore_above like so:
"example_field": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 20000
    }
  }
}

But it looks like this doesn't actually prevent immense terms in keyword fields.
Ideally, my app would distinguish between short and long text fields so I didn't have to index everything as both text and keyword. But as that isn't the case now, is there a way I can limit the max length of the keyword field, but not of the text field?

The problem was that I had set ignore_above too high:
"example_field": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 20000
    }
  }
}

That will work for English text, but not for e.g. Chinese text. ignore_above will configure the character limit, but Lucene's internal limit is 32766 bytes.
So a safe limit to set is ignore_above: 8000. Unicode characters are at most 4 bytes, and 8000*4 = 32000, which is still below the limit.

The text and keyword field types just works as you wanted.

In other words, there is no hard limit for text but keyword.

So when you index a long string (by default long mean is more than 256 characters), the keyword field type will be dropped/ignored but you can continue to use text field type for search.

If you would like to limit the length you can use ingest pipeline. There is an example here.

Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately that's not the behaviour I'm seeing. When I try to index a long field, I get errors like {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Document contains at least one immense term in field=\"content.keyword\" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.'}
